# Blend colors with markers

Tags: drawing, markers, blending

I have experience with drawing with color pencils, water colors and pastel. Now I want to try it with markers. As I am a newbie to markers, I have a lack of knowledge about those. I wonder if it is hard to blend colors when using markers?

Comment: Do you mean water-based or solvent-based markers?

Comment: Actually I'm new to markers. So I don't have much idea about what marker type I should use.

Comment: Its been a while, but a little tip: lots of markers (like Copic, Ohuhu,) have a blender marker that you can buy. Its a marker with only the marker ink base (no pigment so no color, its clear) that can also be used to blend colors together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to blend using markers, though like any new medium it can take some practice as well as depend on the type of marker you're using.

**Water-based markers**

Blending water-based markers requires little to no additional special equipment, just some water and a way to apply it. As you mention experience with watercolors, this may feel fairly intuitive to you. You'll use either a standard brush or a [water brush](https://www.jetpens.com/Pentel-Vistage-Water-Brush-Medium/pd/1774) (a hollow brush pen that can be filled with water) to apply water to your paper and fade or blend your colors. Additionally, you can use a non-porous surface to build up some ink from the marker and use it very similarly to paint by picking the ink back up off that surface with your brush/water brush.

The blog [The Frugal Crafter](https://thefrugalcrafter.wordpress.com/tag/blending-watercolor-markers/) has an entry showing a wide variety of samples of both test blending and artwork done using inexpensive water-based markers and brushes to blend.

Brands include Tombow, Marvy LePlume, Crayola, Mr. Sketch, etc.

**Alcohol-based markers**

With alcohol based markers, the key to blending is to work while the ink is still wet; this can mean working quickly from one color to another on the page, touching the tips of two markers together, or applying one marker to a nonporous surface and picking the color up with another. Additionally, many brands feature a "colorless blender" pen that contains only the solvent and can be used to help fade a color into the paper's color.

User [Khallandra on DeviantArt](https://www.deviantart.com/khallandra/journal/PE-Tips-for-Blending-with-Markers-527590028) offers a nice rundown of various blending techniques with a large number of sample images.

Brands include Copic, Prismacolor, etc.

**Solvent-based markers**

Solvent-based (xylene, etc) markers may behave fairly similarly to alcohol-based markers, and even may include the option of a colorless blender for them. Their blending is not as smooth as that of alcohol-based markers, however this may vary to some degree by brand. I'll note that while I personally have used them in the past, it was briefly and some time ago due to the heavy fumes released by the solvents, which can cause eye and lung irritation.

[The Curiously Creative](https://www.thecuriouslycreative.com/topics/the-complete-beginners-guide-to-art-markers/) blog has a guide to general marker types, which has the best general, neutral information I could find on solvent-based markers.

Brands include Sharpie, Chartpak, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to blend colors with markers and you can't use normal paper for it because on rough paper marker spreads so you need a proper sketch paper.

Comment: Sorry, everything here is incorrect.